# Framebuffers can't store floating point numbers

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've tried to implement deferred shading but the gbuffer can't store any floating point numbers. The edges from the lighting is VERY rough since the framebuffer can't store negative components for the normals eventhough i passed in the correct internal format and data type.

[Example picture of the rough edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jRWM.png)

Texture generation:

```
    public TextureResource(int width, int height, int filter, int internalFormat, int format, boolean clamp, int dataType, ByteBuffer data) {
    id = glGenTextures();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, dataType, data);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, filter);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, filter);
    if(clamp) {
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Framebuffer generation:

```
this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.attachments = attachments;
    boolean hasDepth = false;
    IntBuffer drawBuffers = Util.createIntBuffer(attachments.length);
    assert(attachments.length <= MAX_ATTACHMENTS);
    framebuffer = glGenFramebuffers();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    for(int i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
        if(attachments[i].getAttachmentType() == GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT) {
            drawBuffers.put(GL_NONE);
            hasDepth = true;
        } else {
            drawBuffers.put(attachments[i].getAttachmentType());
        }
        if(attachments[i].getAttachmentType() == GL_NONE) {
            continue;
        }
        attachments[i].createTexture(width, height);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, attachments[i].getAttachmentType(), GL_TEXTURE_2D, attachments[i].getTexture().getId(), 0);
    }
    if(!hasDepth) {
        renderbuffer = glGenRenderbuffers();
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer);
    }
    drawBuffers.flip();
    glDrawBuffers(drawBuffers);
    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        System.err.println("Framebuffer creation failed!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

GBuffer:

```
super(width, height, new FramebufferAttachment(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_NEAREST, GL_RGB32F, GL_RGB, false, GL_FLOAT),
                         new FramebufferAttachment(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_NEAREST, GL_RGB32F, GL_RGB, false, GL_FLOAT),
                         new FramebufferAttachment(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_NEAREST, GL_RGB, GL_RGB, false, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE));
```

Geometry pass fragment shader:

```
    #version 330 core

in vec3 worldPos0;
in vec2 texCoord0;
in vec3 normal0;

layout (location = 0) out vec3 gWorldPos;
layout (location = 1) out vec3 gNormal;
layout (location = 2) out vec3 gColor;

uniform sampler2D diffuse;

void main() {
    gWorldPos = worldPos0;
    gNormal = normalize(normal0);
    gColor = texture(diffuse, texCoord0).xyz;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's because it is 3.3 core. OpenGL standard somewhat contradicts itself on the matter of what format are renderable, some implementations *actually* support RGBxF formats. OpenGL 4.4 specs declare them renderable.

Ifit is *really* needed, I think  is it possible to map integer values to floating point. Ofc you still have limited  amount of values, but you can implement negative  and fraction values, while having limited range

Comment: Switched the shader version to 450, did not fix the problem.

Comment: @stringflow should either try  http://www.gamedev.net/topic/560908-is-float-point-framebuffer-possible-with-opengl/  or use more universal workaround of mapping values.. e.g. 0..65535 would map to what? -1.0f ...1.0f ? A LSB of short  int value would be equal to 1/(2^17)  (least significant bit value)with delta of -1.0f

Comment: I've already tried every single internal format and it does not work with any. I really would just use the offical opengl feature instead of writing a hack around it. Also every single tutorial on things like HDR or Deferred Shading suggest using the floating point internalformats to draw to the framebuffers, so I don't really see a point on writing a hack around it. It clearly can't be a driver issue cause other programs using exactly this method of implementing it run just fine.

Comment: @stringflow are you using core mode only? As I understand,  that's the issue with core mode, those formats not supported there. And about hacks.. Otherwise it is not supported on stange GPUS that use non-IEEE754  float point format. I saw plenty of production code (aka, real existing games or  applications)that used all kind of mathematical "hacks" to supply more data to shaders, especially while rendering mesh, animations or instanced rendering, as long as it doesn't use some fleeting platform depending feature

Comment: @stringflow e.g. Rasberry Pi's GPU hardware doesn't support it, you can only hack around that or comply

Comment: Well, i recoded the whole deferred renderer and it somehow works now. I have no clue what cause this bug (I'm still using 3.3 core). Thanks for your help anyways!!